# Is this how we consider force per unit area for the term pressure?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image]

Red = Cylinder of mass 30kg filled with air inside

Blue= table

Now,

I think that force should be exerted only till the area of table . Let us say it is 0.5m^2.

Yellow is that area of cylinder which is from bottom to the top.

Green is the portion not covered or that area which couldn’t reach the table.

My questions :

Know , we know about centre  of mass(Where mass of whole system is concentrated ).

So , should we say the mass of yellow area * acceleration of only that yellow area which ultimately should be acceleration of whole red cylinder  = m * g = Force exerted on that area of table = 0.5m^2.That means we should consider centre of mass for only that yellow region ?

I am not getting is how to calculate that weight which is present only in that yellow region. and also am not sure if I am correct or wrong.

Please do help.

NOTE : It is not that there is a cylinder inside cylinder.The yellow lines and green lines are just for imagination.

Comment: There is no acceleration here. None of the pieces is accelerated.  You have a statics problem. All pieces are in equilibrium so the net force on the whole cylinder as well as on any piece should be zero.

Comment: Net force is of course zero.Doesn’t mean the Value of Normal and force which will be concentrated on that Body is 0.

Comment: This means that the normal force is equal to the weight of the cylinder. And the normal force on the table is also equal to the weight of the cylinder. If you look at the lateral pieces, they are not directly supported by the table but by the internal shear forces but the overal effect (on the table) is the same as when the cylinder is completely on the table.

Comment: Also the entire weight of the cylinder is opposed by the table, you can't just chop off part of the cylinder and ignore that mass.

Comment: @Triatticus What should the answer then

Comment: What is the question? The pressure on the table is the weight of the cylinder divided by the contact area.

Comment: @nasu yes.I want to know exactly how much weight is present or pressure is  present on that table

Comment: There is no weight "on the table". The force acting on the table is equal to the weight of the cylinder.  The pressure on the table i already mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: @nasu What is the contact area exactly I didn’t understand.If I ask you this in terms of just the diagram right , I want to know can we really say by looking at diagram or as you have said that there is contact area(Is it action reaction pair you are saying normal 1 and normal 2) , then can we show it by FBD ?

Comment: @nasu I am understand your point sir and where I am going wrong.

Comment: By contact area i mean the area of the surface where the two bodies are in contact, whete they touch each other.  The normal force is distributed over this contact area. The normal force does not depend on the contacy area.  The pressure does.

Comment: So , is this right to say @nasu  $\frac{weight of cylinder = 30kg}{Contact area = 0.5m^2}$.

Comment: To say what about it? That is the pressure on the table? The weight is a force in newtons.  30 kg is the mass.  If you put in the correct weight and if the contact atea is 0.5 m2, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the object has an uniform mass distribution, we can imagine the object in this way: cut the object vertically in many equally pieces (infinitely thin pillars)‌, and you can see that each piece has its own pressure, i.e:
$$ dP= \frac{dF}{dA} $$
Hope this argument helps.

Comment: Ok.It is right but when we take that cylinder on a table.Force at centre of cylinder is sum of all the masses of that small pieces present in the whole Body.So , in that way , Each piece does have pressure dp but I think it should be when it is air . it becomes different when that whole body is put onto a table.Since pressure form the sides and top is not same.What do you think ?

Comment: @user282675 You've got confused in so many ways... mass of the cylinder is not in center of the object! We generally (for objects with symmetry) consider its "center of mass" in its center, due to its symmetry, and most of the time we use this fact when the object is in motion to calculate anything we want. And pressure from sides is not relevant, since you only want to calculate the force perpendicular to the desired surface. I think you should have a closer look to the definitions of pressure and center of mass.

Comment: So.Ok do you mean to say that I am right.Since that is what I have written .a only they

Comment: The yellow portion mass I considered

Comment: What should be the answer